# Can I add an entirely new instance of the same jPanel while having access to the previous one?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm new here, and this is my first question:
I'm trying to make a question and answer (pop quiz) program, i've gone through alot of hurdles by checking out answers from previous questions, but i ran into a confusing one.

I place a radio button in a jPanel and made it final and static in order to retain its selected status, i'm trying to avoid making multiple jPanel classes (using NetBeans GUI builder) and decided to use only one Jpanel class. But my problem is, each time i press the next button, it still shows the same page(with the radio button still selected). How can i make an entirely new Jpanel, but still similar to the original one?

here's my code sample:

```
package pages;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

/**
 *
 * @author Hendy
 */
public class page1 extends javax.swing.JPanel {


/**
 * Creates new form page1
 */
public page1() {
    initComponents();

}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jRadioButton1.setText("first");

    jButton1.setText("next");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(176, 176, 176)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
            .addContainerGap(179, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(30, 30, 30))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(131, 131, 131)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 96, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(27, 27, 27))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    removeAll();
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    invalidate();
    page1 on = new page1();
    add(on,BorderLayout.NORTH );
    revalidate();
}                                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private static final javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *"I place a radio button in a jPanel and made it final and static in order to retain its selected status"*  That doesn't make any sense.  Keeping a reference to an existing control will also maintain its state.  It has nothing to do with either `final` or `static`.

Comment: *"(using NetBeans GUI builder)"*  Nope.  It seems like it's using you.  Stop it from doing that by putting aside the 'magic painting box' for a while & learning how to code Java.

Comment: when i used multiple Jpanels, switching between them always caused the radio buttons to reset to un-selected mode. making it final and static stopped the reset. now i'm trying to do the same thing with only a single panel, so i can implement a next question and previous question feature. pls pardon my java noobiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a JPanel, you must also have a container holding that JPanel. Most probably it is a JFrame; anyway - if you have a container, most probably you put your JPanel in it with function `add(Component component)`. Try different approach:

1. In your container create a static field that will store your `page1`. If you use stock JFrame, simply extend it.
   From what I imagine, every single `page1` represents a single question in quiz, so you want this field to be some kind of collection to store all your questions.
2. Collection type - this is up to you, but I think `Map`, `Set`, `List` would be the most handy. What you want to do is put all your questions here and you can do it in for example in container constructor. I'll use `Map` here, but feel free to use any other type of collection if you want.
3. You want your `Map` to store the question number and its JPanel, so let's have
   `Map<Integer, page1> map = new HashMap<Integer, page1>();`
   Fine, now put all your questions here.
4. Generate yourself a static getter of that `Map`.
5. Now, if you press next/previous question button, you call your static map getter from the container, `get` your `page1` with the correct number of question that would be previous/next one and make it shown by putting it in your container with function `setContentPane(Component chosenComponent)`.

This way you have access to all your questions. I hope now it's easier to understand. 
Speaking of chosen answers - wouldn't it be a better idea to create additional field in your `page1` class that would simply store what the user chose and according to that field a proper answer would be checked on next/previous button clicked?

Example below:
Create a field in your JPanel to store your answer - whatever type you want, it may as well be an int. So, you have in your `page1` field `private int chosenAnswer;`. Now, when you create all your questions (probably when putting them in the `Map` from the solution above), initialize your variable chosenAnswer = 0; (simply put it in `page1` constructor). Now, when the previous/next button is clicked, check all your radio buttons if some of them is clicked. If first is, chosenAnswer = 1; etc. If none of them is leave 0. This is clear, I believe.
Now, you want to get this information back somehow, when you come back to the question that had previously checked answer. To do this, try this approach:

1. Create in your `page1` function `public void setAnswer()`. You want this function to check the value of that int `chosenAnswer` - you can do it with `switch` or simply multiple `if`. This `chosenAnswer` is gonna match the answer that was previously checked.
2. When you find proper `JRadioButton`, that needs to be checked, call the function [setSelected](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelected(boolean)) inherited from `AbstractButton`, for example `firstRadioButton.setSelected(true)` if the value of `chosenAnswer == 1`.
3. Now ind the place in your code, where you `setContentPane(chosenQuestion)` and before that line put `chosenQuestion.setAnswer();`.

Comment: okay..... it's gonna take a while for that to sink in. your idea of storing what the user chose is great, i'll go with that. but i still  don't get the whole set page stuff

Comment: @Mofe-hendyEjegi I improved my answer, you should check this out now.

Comment: errthing was going fine until i got to the getting part, really confused about it all

Comment: @Mofe-hendyEjegi what step exactly is confusing to you? You don't know how to get that `Map`, `page1` for specific question or what?

Comment: really don't mean to be a pain in the ass, but my issue lies in this part: " wouldn't it be a better idea to create additional field in your page1 class that would simply store what the user chose and according to that field a proper answer would be checked on next/previous button clicked?"

Comment: storing of the clicked info - i'm through with the rest, but still having issues with storing the radio button value.

Comment: @Mofe-hendyEjegi no problem, some day you will help somebody with patience. I added example to my answer - I don't have access to my IDE, so I couldn't check this solution myself, but there is no reason why this would not work. However, if it is still not working, feel free to let me know.

Comment: thank you sooooo much, my idea was to store the radio button value in an 'ArrayList' upon next button click, then when i go back to that question, according to the value of the arraylist, it does the  setSelected(true)stuff. I'll try urs if mine doesn't work